# Image Sequence Render Awfully Pixelated

Tags: rendering, animation, blender-internal-render-engine, video-sequence-editor, video

I've rendered an animation into images in the hope of then combining them together as a image sequence and then into a video file. However after doing this in the Video Sequence Editor and then rendering it again, the final video is terribly pixelated (see below) and there is a weird swirly bit along the base of it. The original rendered images were not blurred or pixelated at all. Any ideas?

**M.H**

[image]

[image: See? Pixelated!]

Comment: You might have saved the renders with high compression.

Comment: @Dimali Okay... so, what is the solution?